# Is there a way in Mac OS X to stop applications from stealing focus, especially between spaces?

Tags: macos, osx-leopard, osx-spaces

I have certain applications set to open in certain spaces, but would like them to open in the background and not switch the space just so I can watch them open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will prevent any autoswitching of Spaces, which meets your criteria, but does other things, too, that you may not want:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock workspaces-auto-swoosh -bool false
osascript -e 'tell application "Dock" to quit'
```

Comment: Thanks; I'll give it a try. Do you know what other things? Do I just set the boolean back to true to undo it?

Comment: @wfaulk, yes, what are the "other things" this command does?

Comment: @Josh: largely that Cmd-Tab switching to an open application will not switch to a Space with an open window.  Basically anything that would automatically switch you to a different space will be disabled.

Comment: Too bad there doesn't seem to be anything that can just solve the problem without the unwanted side effects. Bummer.

Answer (score 10):

There is also the '-g' option to 'open' that will run programs in the 'background' in that they won't steal focus away from the current app.  Try

```
open -g /Applications/iCal.app
```

for instance.  See [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html) for details:

If you want to edit the Info.plist of some application to make this permanent, you can add the key

```
<key>LSBackgroundOnly</key>
<true/>
```

See [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009250-SW1) for details.

Comment: This is nonetheless very interesting.... Maybe there is after all a more permanent way to make the open -g style change w/o other side-effects?

Answer (score 1):

(above user refused to let me cite the official documentation in my edits to his answer, so I'm adding it for the benefit of actual users who want to get the authoritative source of truth)

From `man open`

```
      -g  Do not bring the application to the foreground.
```

Example:

```
open -g -a /Applications/TextWrangler.app /path/to/myFile.txt
```

Comment: This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.

Comment: No it is not the same as the above answer, mine gives the manpage reference which is helpful. I attempted to modify the above answer but my edits were rejected. I don't want to go reading through manpages to find out what `-g` officially means.

Comment: The other answer includes a link to the appropriate manpage.

Comment: Please read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: "A link alone as an answer is a bad answer in my book. Links break and the answer becomes worthless later even if the linked material answered the question initially. At least if you include a summary, the answer can somewhat stand on its own."

Comment: I don't need to. "Are answers that just contain links" the other answer contain far more information than just links. It also says "I think that links are fantastic, but they should never be the only piece of information in your answer." which it clearly isn't.

Comment: "There is also the '-g' option to 'open' that will run programs in the 'background' in that they won't steal focus away from the current app." is a more than adequate summary of what is needed from the first link.

Comment: Bottom line, users in search of the answer to the question will not want to just blindly copy the `-g` flag without doing the proper research. I'm speaking from experience.

Comment: I don't want users paraphrasing when official verbiage could easily have been cited.

Comment: If this was refused as an edit (I see why), then you could have added this information as a comment to that answer...